# How could I symbolize an axis in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, accents

I am doing a course on rotational movement of solid rigid objects and a professor of the MIT symbolizes the axis around which the object rotates with a symbol that is a letter with a vertical line on top of it and another one below it. Is there a simple way to do that in a line of LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hi, you can define a command `\newcommand{\s}{\tikz{\draw node {\LARGE $|$} node [fill=white] {$S$};}}` then call it wherever you need it by writing `\s`. I hope this helps

Comment: @stargazer45, nice as it looks, the result doesn't fit well with text, e.g. from mismatching baselines etc.

Comment: Venturi365, please add a little more details to your questino, like: a) Where does the symbol you posted come from?, b) Has the symbol to fit with current text or not?, c) Is it intended to be a larger visual object? Etc. Perhaps you can post a screenshot of "this symbols natural habitat"? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO right thank you, I thought it was needed as a label, I added `[baseline=-1mm]` so here you are `\newcommand{\s}{\tikz[baseline=-1mm]{\draw node {\LARGE $|$} node [fill=white] {$S$};}}`

Comment: @stargazer45, nice. You or the OP might even try replacing `$|$` with `$/$` for a more dynamic look.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `node` containing an argument. Name the node and then you can use `baseline=(A.text)` (assuming the name is `A`). Then you can control every aspect of the line: thickness, length, color, spacing from the text, etc. Set `inner xsep` to 0, and set `inner ysep` to whatever you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rota}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(A.text)]{
    \node[inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1pt](A){$#1$};
    \draw[semithick] (A)--++(0,.2)(A)--++(0,-.2);
}}

\begin{document}

The axis \rota{s} is the axis of rotation.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small vertical bar and the `tipa` font has one.

The only problem is to keep the baseline of the main character, which is solved using a `\vbox` with a nested `\vtop`. The small bar is typeset at a certain height, so it's necessary to lower and smash its depth.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\axis}{m}{%
  \mathord{\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \SMALLVERT\cr
      \noalign{\vskip0.5pt}
      \vtop{%
        \ialign{%
          \hfil##\hfil\cr
          $\mathsurround=0pt #1$\cr
          \noalign{\vskip1pt}
          \SMALLVERT\cr
        }%
      }\cr
    }%
  }}%
}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{cmrtipa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{cmrtipa}{m}{n}{<-> tipa10}{}

\newcommand{\SMALLVERT}{%
  \usefont{U}{cmrtipa}{m}{n}%
  \raisebox{-1ex}[\dimeval{\height-1ex}][0pt]{\symbol{34}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\axis{s}+\axis{r}+\axis{x}+\axis{y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]